# EasyPHP Devserver: database server not starting

Tags: php, mysql, windows, easyphp, devserver

EASYPHP DEVSERVER
▪ version : 17.0
HTTP server works, but if I try to start the DATABASE server after the loading spin on the screen, nothing happens and the start button stays green with the play icon. No log, no error show up.

I've already installed Microsoft Visual Studio C++ r. 2015 and 2017 and also make the application starts as administrator.

Please help me solve it.
I'm on Windows 10 64bit. If I missed some info please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. It was due to a conflict with IIS. Also disabling it doesn't make it work but removing mysql manually solved the problem. :)